# Page not found error in Django REST framework tutorial

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am doing the Django REST Framework Tutorial, and I got to the part when they add the view for an individual snippet (view snippet_detail, tutorial 2). When I start the server and point the browser to url http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets, it returns the 3 snippets I have created before (ids:1,2,3), fine. At url http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/2, it returns only the snippet 2, perfect. But when I try http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/1, it raises a Page not found error:

```
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/1/

Using the URLconf defined in tutorial.urls, Django tried these URL 
patterns, in this order:
  ^ ^snippets/$
  ^ ^snippets/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$
  ^admin/
The current path, snippets/1/, didn't match any of these.
```

I don't understand why snippets/1 doesn't match the second url pattern. Can someone please clarify this error and help me overcome this.

Comment: I think you just need to lose that forward-slash at the end

Comment: @patrick please add ```^ ^snippets/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$``` if you want acheive http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/1/

Comment: You're right, thanks to both of you guys. But question: why did it work for snippets/2 without the slash?

Comment: This line ^snippets/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$ will only match your url if the very last character is part of the primary key. IF you add anything afterwards the match fail '$' means end of string in regex talk. So when you add an extra forward slash, it fails to match.

Comment: @MatthewHart: sorry I removed the slash in my original question, it still raises an error without it

Comment: In Django, it chops off whatever part of the URL matched up to that point. Just check this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/

Comment: I still don't understand why it worked for snippets/2 but not for snippets/1 when my url pattern was missing the slash at the end

Comment: You ask why `snippets/1` didn't match, but your error message shows that you tried a different URL `snippets/1/` (with a slash). If you find that you were redirected from `snippets/1` to `snippets/1/`, then perhaps your browser has cached a permanent redirect. To avoid any caching effects you could test using `curl -I  http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/x`. You should get the exact same behaviour for `pk=1` and `pk=2`.

Comment: @Alasdair: sorry when I edited my post to remove the slash at the end of my url address, I forgot to remove it also from the error message it raised. But you're right, it was probably an error related to the cache because the curl command is returning content without error. Thanks to all.

Comment: If there was a redirect, then the error message would be `The current path, snippets/1/` (with a slash). I'd be really surprised if you got an error message `The current path, snippets/1`.

Comment: @alasdair you're right. To recap: without the slash at the end in urls.py, when I request snippets/1, the request is redirected to snippets/1/ and it raises a Page not found error. Curl command with snippets/1 returns content. Probably a cache error as you suggested.